# Ruffle SWF at 100%

Tags: html, css, flash, ruffle

How do you make a SWF scale at 100% using Ruffle flash emulator? [For some reason I have to type more because stack overflow doesn't like my simple question.]

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf8'>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id="container"> </div>

       <script>
          window.RufflePlayer = {
            config: {
              autoplay: "on",
            wmode: "transparent",
            scale: "showAll",
              unmuteOverlay: "hidden",
            }
          };
       </script>
    
       <script>
          window.RufflePlayer = window.RufflePlayer || {};
          window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
              const ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest();
              const player = ruffle.createPlayer();
              const container = document.getElementById("container");
              container.appendChild(player);
              player.load("index.swf");
          });
      </script>
      <script src="ruffle/ruffle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try setting width as `player.width=` or `player.style.width=`, if both fail (they shouldn't), you can try same thing on your`<div>` size instead, where you replace `player.` with `container.`

Answer (score 2):

I got it with...

```
player.style.width = "100vw"; 
player.style.height = "100vh";
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `container.style.width` achieve same thing or is there picture issues?