# New Google Sites and running an SWF file

Tags: flash, ruffle

From what I have read, I can add my SWF files to a new google site by using Ruffle.

However, my coding is very limited and I'm very much a novice.

Please could someone please explain how I can do this or write the code I need to make this happen?

Thank you :)

Comment: _"My coding is very limited and I'm very much a novice."_ You need to tell us exactly where you're stuck before we can answer you correctly. Try something and then show a link to your demo page (so we see the problem in action).

Comment: **PS:** If you need a starting point then... **(1)** Does [this guide](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-html-css-or-javascript-code-to-your-site) help you to add some custom HTML into your Google Sites? **(2)** Read the [Ruffle Javascript guide](https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle/wiki/Using-Ruffle#javascript-api) **(3)** Does using this [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73378360/2057709) work for you in Google Sites? Try some code then give us a link to your test page if the SWF (Flash file) is not showing there.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to resolve the problem myself :)